# how to add this jquery to mysite

Tags: php, jquery, html, jsfiddle

i have this jquery i made in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8CfK6/

how to i go about  getting this on my site....

http://pcrepairs.tk/services.php

i have :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

in the head tags

andthen

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
mycode
</script>
```

just before my html  in the body.

it just isnt  working :/ am i putting  the  javascript code  in the wrong place?

Comment: I can't seem to find the script source on your web page, are you sure it's getting added?

Comment: no reason it  shouldnt be  added. i even checked  in my local pageand  still nothing. the code is there when i go to inspect element

Comment: there are so many errors on that page. For example you can only have one head block not 4. you should reassess your ability to sell "Web development" services

Comment: head block? there are 4?

Comment: sorry, elements, and yes there are 4 starting lines 3,13,35 and 309 multiple <body> as well. For javaScript to work you need valid html (or at least close to valid)

Comment: learn html first, that's my helpful tip. Great place to start: http://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/htmlcss

Comment: ok iv just realised my complete maaasssivveee mistake. i have php includes and they have <head> and  <body> tags.... i can do html just fine  thanks . its javascript and php im new to

Comment: well the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpcrepairs.tk%2Fservices.php) does not agree :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work ...

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#web").click(function () {
     $("#contweb").stop().slideToggle();
     return false;
 });
 $("#web").hover(function () {
     $(this).stop().css({
         "cursor": "pointer"
     })
 });

 $("#screen").click(function () {
     $("#contscreen").stop().slideToggle();
     return false;
 });
 $("#screen").hover(function () {
     $(this).stop().css({
         "cursor": "pointer"
     })
 });

 $("#keyboard").click(function () {
     $("#contkey").stop().slideToggle();
     return false;
 });
 $("#keyboard").hover(function () {
     $(this).stop().css({
         "cursor": "pointer"
     })
 });
});
```

Comment: Ugh I was just about to write this. but here is the explanation, JQuery is trying to bind to elements on the page that aren't really there yet putting them in the $(document).ready block will ensure the browser has drawn everything before executing your code

Comment: indeed. or you can put your jquery at the bottom of your webpage, and i THINK it will work without e $(document).ready then .. (correct me if i'm wrong :)

Comment: very true, there are even other possibilities like using $(document).on('click', "#web", function(){ //blah blah}); but I like to use $(document).ready or $(function(){})(less chars) as it will always guarantee exactly what I want it to do.